Can I upgrade an SM-P900 to a newer Android version?
I've gotten an abandoned Samsung Galaxy Note SM-P900 tablet, which is supposed to go to charity. Unfortunately, it sports an Android 5.0.1, a lot of APKs don't install, and many websites can't be accessed by Samsung's bundled browser due to not having a valid security certificate.
Can I upgrade the Android version and otherwise make the life of this device's user less miserable?
I understand there are no relevant official updates, as explained here:
How to upgrade my Android device to latest Android version
But I don't mind flashing this device, and obviously don't mind losing anything stored on it (I've already reset to factory settings anyway). I have a PC running Linux with adb installed, I have some USB cables, and I have a bit of time to spare.

Oh, I should mention a constraint: No use of any Google or Samsung account during this process.

Did you search Lineage OS availability for this device or any custom ROM in XDA//Aside, you are talking of upgrading from Android 5, at a time when Android 15 is expected to roll out soon. IMO, you will not find a custom ROM that is actively supported for such an old device

This question is similar to: How to upgrade my Android device to latest Android version. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@beeshyams: I have heard the name "Lineage OS" but I'm not really familiar with it.  I've never used custom ROMs (or any ROMs for that matter) before. I don't see why Android 15 rolling out is relevant; I don't mind updating to Android 14. "Such an old device" - it was just released 10 years ago, what do you mean "old"?

Old=1.  In custom ROM development , the ROMs need to be developed by somebody and somebody else usually maintains it . This support doesn't usually extend 2 to 3 versions beyond the last stock ROM ( as a thumb rule). So, even you do find a custom ROM say of Android 8, it may not be supported, in the sense no one is going to fix bugs 2. Play Store places restrictions, so some of the apps you want to install may not be able to run //

It was in this context I meant old, besides practically the battery would be very weak and you may need to replace it// Lineage OS is a well known custom ROM that meets the constraints you mentioned // There may be others, you'd need to search// Look at the graph for point 2

@beeshyams: Thanks for the tip regarding the battery, you're probably right. // About the graph - is that about the Play Store restrictions, or something more general? I'm not using Play Store in this process (no Google Account).

It's for Play Store meaning apps you may want to install from Play Store. If all your apps are going to be from other sources, you may still need to check if they run on your installed custom ROM version

XDA Forums for selection of custom ROMs (don't worry about the "UNOFFICIAL" label, they are unofficial because they are not maintained by the official custom ROM organization)
